# Use linux perf utility to report counters every second like vmstat

Tags: linux, performancecounter, perf

There is `perf` command-linux utility in Linux to access hardware performance-monitoring counters, it works using `perf_events` kernel subsystems.

`perf` itself has basically two modes: `perf record`/`perf top` to record sampling profile (the sample is for example every 100000th cpu clock cycle or executed command), and `perf stat` mode to report total count of cycles/executed commands for the application (or for the whole system).

Is there mode of `perf` to print system-wide or per-CPU summary on total count every second (every 3, 5, 10 seconds), like it is printed in `vmstat` and systat-family tools (`iostat`, `mpstat`, `sar -n DEV`... like listed in http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/11/linux-performance-analysis-in-60s.html)? For example, with cycles and instructions counters I will get mean IPC for every second of system (or of every CPU).

Is there any non-`perf` tool (in https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial or  http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) which can get such statistics with `perf_events` kernel subsystem? What about system-wide per-process IPC calculation with resolution of seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `perf stat` option "interval-print" of `-I N` where N is millisecond interval to do interval counter printing every N milliseconds (N>=10): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html

> ```
>   -I msecs, --interval-print msecs
>        Print count deltas every N milliseconds (minimum: 10ms) The
>        overhead percentage could be high in some cases, for instance
>        with small, sub 100ms intervals. Use with caution. example: perf
>        stat -I 1000 -e cycles -a sleep 5
>
>   For best results it is usually a good idea to use it with interval
>    mode like -I 1000, as the bottleneck of workloads can change often.
> ```

There is also importing results in machine-readable form, and with `-I` first field is datetime:

> With -x, perf stat is able to output a not-quite-CSV format output ...  optional usec time stamp in fractions of second (with -I xxx)

`vmstat`, systat-family tools `iostat`, `mpstat`, etc periodic printing is `-I 1000` of perf stat (every second), for example system-wide (add -A to separate cpu counters):

```
  perf stat -a -I 1000
```

The option is implemented in builtin-stat.c http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=4.8  `__run_perf_stat` function

```
531 static int __run_perf_stat(int argc, const char **argv)
532 {
533         int interval = stat_config.interval;
```

For `perf stat -I 1000` with some program argument (`forks=1`), for example `perf stat -I 1000 sleep 10` there is interval loop (`ts` is the millisecond interval converted to `struct timespec`):

```
639                 enable_counters();
641                 if (interval) {
642                         while (!waitpid(child_pid, &status, WNOHANG)) {
643                                 nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
644                                 process_interval();
645                         }
646                 }
666         disable_counters();
```

For variant of system-wide hardware performance monitor counting and `forks=0` there is other interval loop

```
658                 enable_counters();
659                 while (!done) {
660                         nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
661                         if (interval)
662                                 process_interval();
663                 }
666         disable_counters();
```

`process_interval()` http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=4.8#L347 from the same file uses [`read_counters();`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=4.8#L334) which loops over event list and invokes [`read_counter()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=4.8#L286) which [loops over](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/builtin-stat.c?v=4.8#L306) all known threads and all cpus and starts actual reading function:

```
306         for (thread = 0; thread < nthreads; thread++) {
307                 for (cpu = 0; cpu < ncpus; cpu++) {
...
310                         count = perf_counts(counter->counts, cpu, thread);
311                         if (perf_evsel__read(counter, cpu, thread, count))
312                                 return -1;
```

[`perf_evsel__read`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/util/evsel.c?v=4.8#L1207) is the real counter read while program is still running:

```
1207 int perf_evsel__read(struct perf_evsel *evsel, int cpu, int thread,
1208                      struct perf_counts_values *count)
1209 {
1210         memset(count, 0, sizeof(*count));
1211 
1212         if (FD(evsel, cpu, thread) < 0)
1213                 return -EINVAL;
1214 
1215         if (readn(FD(evsel, cpu, thread), count, sizeof(*count)) < 0)
1216                 return -errno;
1217 
1218         return 0;
1219 }
```